# How to reduce Service Control Manager audit logging "Audit Success"

Tags: windows-server-2019, windows-event-log, eventviewer

Maybe this is a niche complaint but it's bloody annoying to have Event Viewer show hundreds of Service Control Manager log entries telling me everything is fine, like:

> The Device Setup Manager service entered the running state.

> The Software Protection service entered the stopped state.

I know one can filter stuff in the Event Viewer, but having many entries there that basically amount to "Nothing to see here, move along" is  pointless.